# Socket Programming - Python

Tags: python

I'm referring : https://bedfordsarah.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/python-socket-programming-project-1-http-web-server/. However, I'm getting error : a Byte like object is required not string
Also, when I'm trying to encode the string into bytes, it is only rendering the closing tags.

Please help me with the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add b before your string eg.b'string'..you can only send data in bytes format.so we have to convert string to bytes else use bytes(string) and the send

Answer (score 0):

You can use encode() and decode() function to encode and decode strings as shown below to convert between string to bytes and vice versa.

```
s = 'abcd'
e = s.encode()
d = e.decode()
print(s)
print(e)
print(d)
```

Output...

```
abcd
b'abcd'
abcd
```

Use the above functions to decode the data recevied from the socket using recv() function and encode() the data that needs to be sent with the send() function.

```
data_from_socket = your_socket.recv().decode()
data_to_socket   = data_from_socket.ecnode()
your_socket.send(data_to_socket)
```